# What does observer.complete() do?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

In **rxjs** what exactly does the observer.complete() do after observer.next() ?

Comment: See http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html, I'm sure you can find  similar questions like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097158/how-can-i-complete-observable-in-rxjs

Comment: What the documentation didn't tell me is that if it unsubscribes the observable as well or not ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/MiscJSDoc.js~ObserverDoc.html) `observer.complete` **notifies** the `Observer` that the **Observable** has finished sending push-based notifications.

In the other hand, `observer.complete` it's a **callback** function and an **Observable** calls this method after it has called **next()** for the final time, if it has not encountered any **errors**.

Comment: So basically it automatically unsubscribes from the observable ?

Comment: Yah I was wondering the same thing.  Is that equivalent to automatically unsubscribing?

Comment: I had the same question & tested it out, it seems like the observers stop receiving notifications once calling observer.complete(), which makes me think calling complete() effectively is unsubscribing the observers.

Answer (score 5):

In ReactiveX library, there are two types of messages.

First ones are ordinary messages. Ordinary messages are the ones sent with `.next()` and there can be 0-many of them.

Second type are notifications. These can be of two types - error and success. The error is sent with `.error()` and give some error details in it (like exception) and success is sent with `.complete()` meaning that there will intentionally be no messages. Every observable should end with a single error or a single success notification.