# rxjs how to complete observable?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, rxjs

To learn rxjs im playing around with it.
My code:

```
// RxJS v6+
import { withLatestFrom, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

const source = interval(1000);

const example = source.pipe(
  map(value => value +1),
  map(value => {
    if(value === 40) {
      finish();
    }
    else if (value % 5 === 0){
      return 'can devide by 5 we did some magic';
  }else{
     return value;
  } })
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(
  val => console.log(val), 
  error => console.log("Error handled: " , error), 
  () => console.log('resolved'));
```

My idea was to  run it 40 time and than finish the observable (it could be another requirement e.g. see if the value is 10 at 10:00 (main goal is to do an evaluation with value and force a finish)).
Im looking for an alternative to the placeholder finish() because finish does not exist. How can I get to the resolve function `() => console.log('resolved')` of the subscribe method?

I found [How can I complete Observable in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097158/how-can-i-complete-observable-in-rxjs) but the answer is from 2015 and im assuming by now there is an answer for the current rxjs version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

both answers mention takeuntil and take are correct but another way is to use the subscription object to unsubscribe it just another option

```
const subx= example.subscribe(val =>  { 
   console.log(val); 
   if (val == 40) {
    subx.unsubscribe() 
   }
 });
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqy75i)

**Updated**

in case you have a many subscribers and you want to put the condtion that complate a source observable take operator can do the job here

```
const source = interval(1000).pipe(take(5)); // 

source.pipe(map(res => res * 10)).subscribe(val => {
  console.log("", val);
});

source.subscribe(val => {
  console.log(val);
});
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tc1m2a)

Comment: Thanks this solves the problem will accept, it would be great if there was a way to send a complete from the observable. lets imagine i have 1000 subscribers now i have to add a comparision to all the observers instead of 1 time in the observable and than broadcast a finish.

Comment: @SvenvandenBoogaart you can in that case use take operator , I will update my answer

Comment: @malbarmawi that doesnt solve the case where I want to do a finish based on an state e,g, if the value is 10 at 10:00. the first solution is the best so far.

Answer (score 8):

Actually is still the same you only need to use pipe operator. You can view example [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/takeuntil)

```
import { interval, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

const source = interval(1000);
const timer$ = timer(5000);
const example = source.pipe(takeUntil(timer$));
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, lets say I want to do something time based e.g. finish if we have a value of 10 at 10:00 so a specific if case, can we do something like source.pipe(takeUntil(value === 10 && time === 10:00) . the main goal of the question is to see if i can 'force' a finish if a specific case arises.

Comment: Yes you can by using takeUntil and takeUntil take in observable as an argument

Comment: You can try with @malbarmawi answer. Manually unsubscribe is ok in this case

Comment: I like takeUntil operator 

Answer (score 2):

> My idea was to run it 40 time`

For that you can add `take(40)`. In general there are several operators like `take` that can complete an observable. Check out https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html

```
// RxJS v6+
import { withLatestFrom, map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

const source = interval(1000);

const example = source.pipe(
  take(40),
  map(value => value +1),
  map(value => {
    if(value === 40) {
      finish();
    }
    else if (value % 5 === 0){
      return 'can devide by 5 we did some magic';
  }else{
     return value;
  } })
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(
  val => console.log(val), 
  error => console.log("Error handled: " , error), 
  () => console.log('resolved'));
```

Comment: it could be another requirement but just to keep te example easy i picked the 40, it could be for example finish if the counter is 10 at 10:00. so that we have to do an evauluation of the value.

Comment: Where does finish come from ?

Comment: @TonyNgo Im looking how I can send a complete/finish, the force is pseudo code, it does not exist. I want to end in the complete method of the subscriber.

Comment: In that case you can take another take operator - takeUntil. Example: `takeUntil(timer(targetDate - new Date()))`

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but there is a clear solution that hasn't been mentioned. To complete an observable based on a condition, simply use the `takeWhile` operator:

```js
const source = interval(1000);

const example = source.pipe(
  takeWhile(n => n < 40),
  map(n => n % 5 ? n : 'can divide by 5 we did some magic')
);
```

All of the `take*` operators will cause the observable to complete:

- [`takeWhile`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/takeWhile) - complete when the given condition fails
- [`takeUntil`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/takeUntil) - complete when the given observable emits
- [`take`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/take) - complete when the given number of emissions has occurred

---

In the above example, since we just want the first 40 values, we could simply use `take(40)` instead of `takeWhile(n => n < 40)`.

The takeWhile operator can be used when the expression is more complex:

`takeWhile(n => n < 40 && !isTimeExpired())`

Comment: Thank you! Now I can stop banging my head on my desk! ...for now (on to the next bug)