# HTTP Interceptor doesn't complete (i.e. finalize is never called)

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-http-interceptors

<s>In my angular 8 project I implemented the simplest possible `HttpInterceptor` that just passes the request by, without doing any action</s>:

In my angular 8 project I implemented a simple `HttpInterceptor` that just clones the original request and adds a parameter:

```js
@Injectable()
export class RequestHeadersInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // original code return next.handle(request) // pass-by request as-is

    return next.handle(request.clone({
      params: request.params.set('language', 'en') }
    ));
  }
}
```

In my service I then have a `getFoos()` method that makes an HTTP call which will be intercepted by the `RequestHeadersInterceptor`:

```js
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { finalize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Foo } from '.';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class FooService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getFoos() {
    return this.http.get<Foo[]>('/foos')
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => console.log('observable completed!'))
      );
  }
}
```

In my component I finally subscribe to `getFoos()`:

```js
fooService.getFoos().subscribe(console.log);
```

**Expected Output**

```
[{ foo: 1　}, { foo: 2 }]
observable completed!
```

**Actual Output**

```
[{ foo: 1　}, { foo: 2 }]
```

As you can see, the `finalize` is never triggered. Why is that?

**Notes**

- if the interceptor is removed, the `finalize` is triggered which is the expected behaviour for both scenarios
- How I provide the interceptor to the module:

```js
import { HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestHeadersInterceptor } from './shared/http-requests';

@NgModule({
  providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestHeadersInterceptor, multi: true },
  ]
);
```

- I updated the interceptor code since I wrongly stated, that the issue persists even when passing-by the request as-is. Instead, it needs to be cloned and changed.
- I added a demo, based on @PierreDuc 's demo (major props!). However, I couldn't reproduce the issue in [the demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rrmn1r). This might have to do with some request or response headers.

**Response Headers on live system API**

```
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0 Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 42
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2020 15:44:33 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Server: nginx/1.16.1
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.1
```

**Request Headers on live system API**

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Authorization: Basic xyzABC123
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Cookie: check=true; anotherCookie=1; bla=2;
Host: some.page.com:11001
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: https://some.page.com
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: What you have looks fine. The problem will be probably somewhere else. Otherwise make a demo that replicates the same problem.

Comment: How are you providing the interceptor in the ngmodule?

Comment: Can you share the code snipped that initializes the interceptor?

Comment: When your http request reponds it doesn't mean that your observable completes. The problem there is that you observable doesn't complete at all. Try to put `take(1)` before the finalize().
How can I complete Observable in RxJS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097158/how-can-i-complete-observable-in-rxjs

Comment: @PierreDuc
I added the code to the original question

Comment: @Ronin I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wyrndu?file=src/app/foo.service.ts), but I do not get your result. So I'm guessing the question is missing some information on what the issue could be. Where do you provide the interceptor?

Comment: @PierreDuc thanks so much! I updated the question, actually a `request.clone` is necessary for the issue to occur. Also, I added the request/response headers from I get in my environment. It might have to do with them, I don't see any other difference.

Comment: @standby954 Thanks, that's actually helpful. While requests from `HttpClient` usually DO complete (it's http, a request/response protocol, so the process terminates after the response is received) in this special setup they don't. However, I just piped a `take(1)` to my `getFoos` method which did the trick in this case. It's still not clear why it happens though.

Answer (score 2):

The "issue" is the [`Connection: Keep-Alive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Connection) header. This persists an open connection

> The Connection general header controls whether or not the network connection stays open after the current transaction finishes. If the value sent is keep-alive, the connection is persistent and not closed, allowing for subsequent requests to the same server to be done.

This will result in a non completing Observable, until the connection is terminated.

So it's not really a bug or issue on your side. I guess in your `HttpInterceptor` you add this header, so that's the reason it's only caused once you add the interceptor